# I can't seem to make navigation drawer work: how to fix this?

Tags: android, android-studio, navigation-drawer

I am new to Android Studio and I'm trying to learn how to use `navigation drawer`. However, I can't make it appear in preview. I have tried doing it automatically when creating a new activity but the result is the same [here is what it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tuf1H.png)

These are the dependencies:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example."
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.5'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want show in editor preview - tools:openDrawer="start"

I found similar question:
[What's the purpose of tools:openDrawer="start" when creating a DrawerLayout (with NavigationView) from the wizard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33341472/whats-the-purpose-of-toolsopendrawer-start-when-creating-a-drawerlayout-wit)